# Pythonic way to represent a UDP package

Tags: python, python-3.x, udp, bitstring

I am looking for a pythonic way to represent a UDP package consisting of different fields with different length and so.

I saw [bitstring](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/walkthrough.html), but the process of defining all the fields and their length is quite cumbersome. I probably need to create a class and create a variable for each field and length and also check that they don't get overwritten by larger numbers and so on.

To me that sounds like a job for a library but I could not find one.

Does anyone know of such a library suitable for this task?

Comment: I don't know a ready-to-use library for an UDP inspection. If you create your own, I would use either a C/C++-Library (e.g. take a look at boost:python) or create a class that inherits or at least heavy uses a bytes object and access methods to be used as an array (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

Comment: [**`struct`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication

Answer (score 1):

The first way is to use a "batteries included"-module like:

- [scapy](https://github.com/secdev/scapy)
- [dpkt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dpkt)
- [pyshark](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark)
- [construct](https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ...etc.

Now if you want to create a custom packet, two ways to do it are either
using [`scapy`](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html) to create a new custom protocol, or you can use [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html) and [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) like so:

```
import os
import struct
from ctypes import *

class myUDP(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("sport",  c_ushort),
        ("dport",  c_ushort),
        ("sum",    c_ushort),
        ("len",    c_ushort)
    ]

    def __new__(self, packet=None):
        return self.from_buffer_copy(packet)

    def __init__(self, packet=None):
        # unpack your data, etc...
        self.srcport  = struct.unpack("H",self.sport)
```

The above is a low-level, simple and as minimal as possible example-representation of the UDP header(*untested*):

---

[image: UDP header]

Though that can a bit difficult to be used in real-world scenarios, with complicated protocols, since it demands a lot of technical work, error handling etc... in order to be a complete packet decoder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scapy for packet manipulation

```
from scapy.all import *
packet = IP(src="1.1.1.1", dst="2.2.2.2")/UDP(dport=4321, sport=123)/"payload"
print str(packet)
# output: 'E\x00\x00#\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x11t\xc4\x01\x01\x01\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x00{\x10\xe1\x00\x0f+?payload'
```

Comment: This is precisely the way I prefer not to do it!

Comment: You can only extract the UDP class representation from scapy, exactly like @game0ver suggested.